# Best way to handle date times with respect to time zones in .Net

Tags: .net, sql-server, timezone, timezone-offset

I have been messing around with time zones lately in a time zone aware web application in .net.  I have come up with the following solution for handling time zones.

**My Solution is:**

- Have the user profile store the time zone they are in.
- On the web server do all the conversions to and from UTC.
- Store the dates in the DB as UTC.

**My Questions Are:**

1. Do you guys believe this to be the best approach in .net?
2. Is using a datetime2 in UTC good enough or should I store the clients time with
       offset in the DB (basically 10-10-2012 4:00:00 vs 10-10-2012
       00:00:00 4:00)?
3. As an aside, some of you will probably notice that while jumps across DST are handled in the server code, passing an offset into a SP or the like on the DB will not handle DST correctly.  Any ideas on this?

**Here is the sample code for time conversions.**

```
    private TimeZoneInfo GetTimeZoneInfo()
    {
        var timeZone = TimeZoneDropdown.SelectedValue;

        switch (timeZone)
        {
            case "Eastern":
                return TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
            case "Central":
                return TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
            case "Mountain":
                return TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time");
            case "Pacific":
                return TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
            case "Alaskan":
                return TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Alaskan Standard Time");
        }

        return TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    }

    public DateTime ConvertLocalDateTimeToUtc(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        var timeZone = GetTimeZoneInfo();

        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), timeZone);
    }

    public DateTime ConvertUtcToLocalDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        var timeZone = GetTimeZoneInfo();

        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc), timeZone);
    }
```

Comment: There is one down side to storing the date time as UTC in the db.  How do you account for DST on the DB side?  There is no way to convert a DateTime or DateTime2 to the users local time with respect to time zones and DST.  If you pass an offset, then you could still be off due to one day being in DST and one not.  Example 3/10/2012 2:00:00 EST is 3/09/2012 20:00:00 UTC but 3/13/2012 2:00:00 EST is 3/12/2012 19:00:00 UTC. Basically an offset of -4 and -5 respectively. So which offset do you pass into your SP -4 or -5 to convert the UTC to local?  Either way one is wrong.

Comment: I think you need to give a bit more information about how the times are going to be used. If it's a time stamp then the database's native timestamp format is (almost certainly) the answer (probably UTC). If it's just to show the user what time they last logged in, then a local time string might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach is not *wrong*, but you could do better by tracking offsets.

When you talk about offsets it seems you are thinking of them as associated with the time zone.  But realize that most time zones have two different offsets, one for standard time, and one for daylight time.  The Microsoft time zone ID for both still has "Standard" in the string, so this can be part of the confusion.  But the `TimeZoneInfo` you are working with is indeed tracking both standard and daylight offsets.

You need to associate the offset with each individual date and time.  And you do that using the `DateTimeOffset` class in .Net, and the `datetimeoffset` data type in SQL Server.

If you use these consistently, then the need to translate to and from UTC goes away.